# How to return the value from a 2 dicts when the key is guaranteed to exist in only one of the dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose you have 2 dicts `d1, d2` and you want to query a key `k`. `k` is guaranteed to exist in exactly one of the dicts. Is there a way to return the value associated with `k` from `d1, d2` without using if statements?

Currently I use if statements:

```
if k in d1.keys():
  return d1[k]
return d2[k]
```

Comment: Use `try`/`except`?

Comment: What have you got against `if` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `ChainMap`

```
from collections import ChainMap
 
d3 =  ChainMap({}, d1, d2) 
return d3[k]
```

Or else use the `|`

```
d3 = d1 | d2  
return d3[k]
```

Last one listed "wins" if both `d1` and `d2` have the key.

Comment: Is the last one an O(max(n,m)) operation where `n = len(d1), m=len(d2)` due to the `d1 | d2`?

Comment: @roulette01 I think the more important topic than time complexity would be the second option makes a new dict containing all kv pairs vs a single object that just refers to both original dicts thus not using as much memory

Comment: @Jab Ah yeah sure. I didn't mention my particular use case, but I do need to maintain separate dictionaries in the eventual code

Comment: The solutions do not overwrite the existing dicts. Yes, ChainMap is more efficient for large dicts. That is rarely meaningful, but if so, you can take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solutions from @Joshua Fox. Here is another one:

```py
return d1.get(k, d2.get(k))
```

The above says

1. If k is in d1, return d1[k]
2. Else, if k is in d2, return d2[k]
3. Else return `None`

Comment: The second solution will obtain `KeyError` when the key exists in `d1` but not in `d2`.

Comment: i mean that's basically a chainmap am i right?

Comment: @Jab That is correct. It is a basic chain map.

Comment: Thank you @MechanicPig, I deleted the second part.

Comment: Efficient solution which should be O(1)